# Reg. Docker Image of microservices in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, serverless

I developed a spring boot-microservices application in which each microservice is packaged into a separate docker container. The databases for these services are also in separate docker containers. Currently, all these are hosted and running in AWS ECS. If I need to migrate to Lambda, can I reuse the same docker containers as such? (of course, I will add the AWS serverless dependency in all the pom.xml files) and do repackaging. Kindly let me know if I can run the modified docker images as such in Lambda?

Thank You

Comment: My doubt is on what we need to do when migrating docker containers in ECS to Lambda. Both for spring boot microservices and databases.

Comment: Is there any link having the step by step procedure, can you share it with me.

Comment: that depends highly on what exactly the current definition looks like, I shared both examples `ECS Task Definition` and `AWS Lambda` example. Depending on them you can make a call, what is needed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't use share the same docker image between your ECS task and Lambda. Because they differ in few aspects and some of them are very specific to lambda, how we write the handler as well as package them.

[New for AWS Lambda – Container Image Support](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/)

Your wording too is a bit confusing

> can I reuse the same docker containers as such?

and then you say

> can run the modified docker images as such in Lambda?

[Example task definitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/example_task_definitions.html)

For Spring Boot Application specifically, you can take a look here:

[Running APIs Written in Java on AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/java-apis-aws-lambda/)

[Java AWS Lambda Container Image Support (Complete Guide)](https://rieckpil.de/java-aws-lambda-container-image-support-complete-guide/)